# SAP Interactive Form archiving

Tags: adobe, abap, interactive

We want to develop an Interactive Form, which should be edited by the user who "created it" via SAP. After the user finished the editing he will be able the choose between two alternatives. On the one hand he will be able to save the final form back to SAP for archiving and on the other hand he can send the form directly via mail.

Question:
How would you solve the problem of this scenario (an interactive form which should be archived in SAP)? What's the best practice for this kind of task and are there any alternatives?

Constraint:
We want to use Smartform texts or footer and header content. Do you think thats the right way?

Thank you all for your advises!

Comment: The meaning of "Archiving" is broad. What is your exact need, what solutions did you think or reject already, why are you "blocked"? (is it simply storing it anywhere, like a file system, a CMS or something else? link it to a business object? define an Archive Object and use the ADK?)

Comment: We want to store the filled-in document and link it to different sap objects (e.g. a customer if it is important for the correspondence with this customer).  I dont have a clear idea how to do this. The "blocker" is getting the filled-in interactive form to store it in SAP. We think we have an idea of storing a print form BAPI_DOCUMENT_CREATE2, but getting the "interactive data" is the problem. Did this answer you questions? Can you give us some advises?

Comment: There are lots of demo programs for retrieving the PDF or the XML inside it (the XML contains user inputs) -> programs FP_PDF_TEST*. Linking documents to business objects is usually done by using Generic Object Services (SO_ATTACHMENT_INSERT_API1 and BINARY_RELATION_CREATE) or ArchiveLink (ARCHIVOBJECT_CREATE_TABLE and ARCHIV_CONNECTION_INSERT).